Intermittent type evaluation
I have a strange case of intermittent type evaluation.  In the code below, when I start typing, the suggestion/autocomplete indicates that it is typed, and suggests correct props etc.  However, once I have finished it and added a value, the type check is gone, and it won't show an error if the property is invalid.
async function go() {
    const orm = new Orm()
    const results = await orm.query({
        table: "tasks",
        limit: 23,  //<-- try deleting this property and retyping with typo, e.g.: `limitt: 23`.
        fields: [
            "id",
            "description",
            { name: "taskType", alias: "type", fields: ["id", "name"] },
            { name: "categories", fields: ["name"], many: true }]
    })

    results.tasks[0].type.id;
    /* (property) tasks: {
        id: any;
        description: any;
        taskType: {
            name: any;
            id: any;
        };
        categories: {
            name: any;
        }[];
    }[] */
}
go()

Full code for interface is below - here is the playground link.
type SortDirection = string

type OrderClause = Array<{
    [key: string]: SortDirection
}>

type LegacyOrderClause = {
    [key: string]: SortDirection
}

type QueryFilter = Record<string, any> | QueryFilter[]

type QueryField = string | QueryFieldObject

type QueryFieldObject = {
    name: string
    many?: boolean
    fields?: QueryField[]
    alias?: string
    filter?: QueryFilter
}

interface Query {
    readonly table: string
    readonly alias?: string
    readonly fields: QueryField[]
    readonly limit?: number
    readonly offset?: number
    readonly filter?: QueryFilter
    readonly order?: OrderClause | LegacyOrderClause
}

export type ExtractTable<Q extends Query> = Q["alias"] extends string ? Q["alias"]: Q["table"]

type QueryResult<Q extends Query> = {
    [K in ExtractTable<Q>]: FieldToData<Q["fields"][number]>[]
}

type OrArray<T, B> =
    B extends true ? T[] : T

type FieldToData<F extends QueryField> = { [T in F as (
    T extends string ? T :
    T extends QueryFieldObject ? (T["alias"] extends string ? T["alias"] : T["name"]) :
    never
)]:
    T extends string ? any :
    T extends QueryFieldObject ? OrArray<
        FieldToData<NonNullable<T["fields"]>[number]>, T["many"]
    > :
    never
} & {}

const getTableRowsFromDb = async (query: Query) => {
    console.log("runs query and gets rows", query)
    return [] as any[]
}

class Orm {
    async query<const Q extends Query>(query: Q): Promise<QueryResult<Q>> {
        return {
            [query.table]: await getTableRowsFromDb(query)
        } as any as QueryResult<Q>
    }
}


async function go() {
    const orm = new Orm()
    const results = await orm.query({
        table: "tasks",
        limit: 23,
        fields: [
            "id",
            "description",
            { name: "taskType", alias: "type", fields: ["id", "name"] },
            { name: "categories", fields: ["name"], many: true }]
    })

    results.tasks[0].type.id;
    /* (property) tasks: {
        id: any;
        description: any;
        type: {
            name: any;
            id: any;
        };
        categories: {
            name: any;
        }[];
    }[] */
}
go()







Q extends Query means it can have any extra property. If you want to try to prohibit extra properties you can try Q extends Query & Record<Exclude<keyof Q, keyof Query>, never> as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write an answer or find a duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

That's it.  Was confused as to how it seemed to know the properties but not restrict them but didn't realise that about "extends".
